# How can I make Woocommerce shopping cart table responsive?

Tags: css, woocommerce, html-table

I'm working with WooCommerce, and I'm trying to style a table that lists all the products on the shopping cart page, so that it becomes responsive. However, I keep running into problems, and now I've been stuck for several hours trying to figure out what's wrong. I can't set a width for anything there. It's like all the `td`s have magic padding around them, and as a result I can't set a `max-width: 100%;` for the table.

[Here's a link to the problem (might be you have to add a product to the basket to see the issue)](http://screenpartner.norisp.no/~interiorbutikken/dev/handlekurv/)

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` after `max-width:100%`?

Comment: The max-width get's registered with and without !important and is an active rule, however it does not make any changes to the broken layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue with Woocommerce where the cart page tables not being responsive, this is how I fixed it:

```
.woocommerce table.cart th,
.woocommerce table.cart td,
.woocommerce #content table.cart th,
.woocommerce #content table.cart td,
.woocommerce-page table.cart th,
.woocommerce-page table.cart td,
.woocommerce-page #content table.cart th,
.woocommerce-page #content table.cart td,
.woocommerce table.shop_table th,
.woocommerce-page table.shop_table th,
.woocommerce table.shop_table td,
.woocommerce-page table.shop_table td {
    min-width: 30px;
}
```

For some reason which I don't really understand, all the table heading and table data needed to have a `min-width`.

Answer (score 0):

That works for viewport with 384px and above, but doesn't seem to work below that. I added max-width: 49px; for down to 360px and then max-width: 39px; for 320px viewport. Hope that helps someone.

Thanks for the work on that!